# Android Design Support Library And Material Design Backwards Compatibility?

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I'm new here, so bear with me!
I'm sorta confused about the new Design Support Library (and how one implements support libraries), and I had a two questions:

- I'm confused about how support libraries are implemented. Is it something as simple as saying 'if the OS version is below version 5.0, use the V7 support library', or would I have to code an ['Alternative Layout'](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#Layouts)(One for devices running +5.0, and one for devices running older version of android?)
- Does the Design Support Library *replace* or *add-to* the V7 support libraries? (If I wanted to include, say, cards and a snack bar in an app, would I be able to just use the Design Support Library or would I have to use it along with the v7 cardview library? I know it's a stupid question, but I just want to make sure.)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) to backport some features introduced with the last api (for example 21) to old devices running a previous api level.

For example, API21 introduced a new widget, the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). This widget can be used only in device with API >=21.

With the `appcompat` rel.21 (a v7 Support library) you can use the  [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) (pay attention to the package) to implement your Toolbar in old devices running API>=7.

This can happen because the support libraries are included in your apk.

The Design Support Library is a new library which add new features.
It contains views as Snackbar, TextInputLayout, FloatingActionButton, but it doesn't contain the Card.

So use this dependency for the design support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

This dependency to use the AppCompat library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

This dependency for the official CardView

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Check the official doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused about how support libraries are implemented. Is it something as simple as saying 'if the OS version is below version 5.0, use the V7 support library', or would I have to code an 'Alternative Layout'(One for devices running +5.0, and one for devices running older version of android?)

The libraries takes care for you of compatibility for pre-Lollipop (and pre-M) devices for the views contained in it.

> Does the Design Support Library replace or add-to the V7 support libraries? (If I wanted to include, say, cards and a snack bar in an app, would I be able to just use the Design Support Library or would I have to use it along with the v7 cardview library? I know it's a stupid question, but I just want to make sure.)

Add-to. The design support library contains some views exclusive for helping to achieve a perfect "materialized" app. For RecyclerView, CardView, Palette etc, you must use their separate support libraries. E.g.:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```